# Eliminar un item de un foreach Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, blade

vengo a postear mi duda porque llevo horas intentando hacer y no hice nada xd.

estoy enviando una colección a mi plantilla blade donde hago un foreach de las horas disponibles, bien me hace el recorrido bien, entonces lo que quiero hacer, sea mediante un if o lo que me sugieran, si encuentra un valor igual al que tengo, no lo muestre y continúe mostrando el resto.

Controlador

```
$start = 08:00;
$end = 17:00;
$intervals = CarbonInterval::hours(1)->toPeriod($start, $end);
            
$data = ['intervals'=>$intervals];
return view('plantilla', $data);
```

Blade

```
<select name="start" class="form-select">
 @foreach($intervals as $date)
  <option value="$date->format('H:i')}}">
    {{ $date->format('g:i a')}}
  </option>
 @endforeach
</select>
```

El select me muestra el rango de horario bien, es decir 8,9,10,11,12, etc etc. Ahora lo que quiero es que si por ejemplo yo diga  `if($date = 08:00){ No mostrar esa hora y que continúe mostrando las demás) }`

He probado y leído con unset() también he probado con list() de los array y nada :/.

Espero puedan iluminarme el camino, y gracias de ante mano.

Edit:
Este es el dd de $date

```
08:00
09:00
10:00
11:00
12:00
13:00
14:00
15:00
16:00
17:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php provee la funcion continue para hacer un break en el loop en este caso podrias intentarlo asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Perdon por colocar el codigo en imagen pero desde la versióm movil no me deja insertar codigo

Comment: Trata de insertar el código aunque sea sin formato y nosotros te ayudamos a arreglarlo, ya que siempre es mejor y puede ayudar mas al op

Comment: No me deja amigo, si inserto el codigo me deshabilita el boton de publicar respuesta y si le doy version de escritorio al oprimir el icono de codigo me dice que la version movil tiene deshabilitada la función :(

Comment: Ok, no hay problema :D solo considera que cuando puedas la edites por favor, bienvenido y gracias por contribuir

Comment: Sip, tan pronto tenga acceso a mi laptop modifico para que el compañero pueda copiarlo, por ahora queria que solucionara el problema

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder pero la respuesta no me funciona, ya había intentando esa forma pero me sigue mostrando todas las horas y lo que quiero es que la hora que compare y sea true, esa hora no me la muestre. 

aca dejo como lo tengo   
`<select name="start" class="form-select">
@foreach($intervals as $date)
@if($date == \Carbon\Carbon::parse($appointment->start)->format('H:i'))
@continue
 @endif
<option value="{{ $date->format('H:i')}}">{{ $date->format('g:i a') }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>`

Comment: Es que estas comparando dos datos distintos , un tipo date con un string, intenta pasar la fecha start a string o haz un gettype() para ver que te devuelve, supongo que te va devolver una instancia de carbon, ese el.problema con las fechas o parseas todo a carbon class o todo a string pero en la comparacion la inferencia de tipos es distinta

Comment: Tienes toda la razón doy como completada mi pregunta, agradecido de ti :D

Comment: @NicolasAldana ahora tendra tiempo?

Comment: Claro, dime que necesitas

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres saltarte las 8 tal y como dices esto debería funcionar

```
<select name="start" class="form-select">
 @foreach($intervals as $date)
  @continue($date->format('H:i') == "08:00")
  <option value="$date->format('H:i')}}">
    {{ $date->format('g:i a')}}
  </option>
 @endforeach
</select>
```